# trouble installing a protocol-buffer known as SentencePiece too, to alleviate the open vocabulary problems in neural machine translation

Tags: audio, artificial-intelligence, pytorch, kaldi

im trying to install a protocol-buffer known as SentencePiece too, to alleviate the open vocabulary problems in neural machine translation .

I used this command as suggested on github documentation :

sudo apt-get install cmake build-essential pkg-config libgoogle-perftools-dev

it gives an error :

eventhough I have cuda10.1 installed .

any ideas ?[image] [image]

Comment: Is the error missing? I don't see it.

Comment: @Kani : no , it is there  : unmet dependencies error , and it suggests cuda 9.2 , whereas i have cuda 10.2(the latest one) , and i dont know why it is causing this error ( this is my first install and encounter of cuda configurations) . I suspect that multiple versions of cuda will cause a conflict on my laptop ...  I dont know what to do to fix this ?  im trying to implement the Espnet toolkit project , if you wanna know ,and it needs the protocol-buffer , which is causing these errors above ...

Comment: ah y was just a lag image load now xD. 
I didn't do much with cuda yet. Used it for tensorflow and it needed same versions then requiered. I think you will also need 9.2 or 9.1 like the screen says for it. Did you tried to install it?

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-91-download-archive

Comment: SOLVED : the package was successfully installed after I had SYNAPTIC installed ! it was the only solution that worked out for me .  Remove broken packages , then sudo apt-get clean , sudo apt-get install -f , sudo dpkh --configure - a , sudo apt-get update .